# High Ping from CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I added CloudFront to my SiteGround-hosted website, but I'm experiencing a latency of about 200ms.
When connected to the nearest regional edge cache (in Brazil), the expected latency should be around 90ms. Similarly, when connected to the nearest AWS Edge Location, the expected latency should be around 40ms.

I have tried checking with

```
tracert oasisdigital.com.ar
  1     1 ms     1 ms    91 ms  ARCHER_XR500V [192.168.1.1]
  2     4 ms     5 ms     5 ms  host-cotesma-161-220-8.smandes.com.ar [201.220.161.8]
  3     2 ms     5 ms    10 ms  10.6.127.45
  4     2 ms     4 ms     3 ms  10.6.127.78
  5     8 ms     5 ms    25 ms  10.32.113.253
  6    22 ms    24 ms    24 ms  8-243-19-6.gblx.net.ar [8.243.19.6]
  7    35 ms    36 ms    46 ms  8-243-19-5.gblx.net.ar [8.243.19.5]
  8   165 ms   178 ms   163 ms  ae2.3601.edge3.Chicago10.level3.net [4.69.206.246]
  9   198 ms   197 ms   197 ms  Google-level3-Chicago10.Level3.net [4.68.127.114]
 10   195 ms   197 ms   196 ms  165.40.208.35.bc.googleusercontent.com [35.208.40.165]
```

and found out I am currently connecting to the edge location in Chicago, USA instead of Buenos Aires, Argentina.

Then I have follow [this Troubleshoot](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/cloudfront-unexpected-edge-location) and checked on my distribution that the price class is "use all edge locations" so that is ok

Then following that guide is were I found an error I guess. When Trying

```
nslookup -type=txt o-o.myaddr.l.oasisdigital.com.ar
```

I get non existing domain

When Trying

```
nslookup -type=txt o-o.myaddr.l.du4or9u9pzqwh.cloudfront.net
```

which is my distribution domain, I get the same non existing domain error

UPDATE:
If I do:

```
nslookup du4or9u9pzqwh.cloudfront.net
```

I get 4 IP adresses from USA

but if I

```
tracert du4or9u9pzqwh.cloudfront.net

Traza a la dirección du4or9u9pzqwh.cloudfront.net [18.164.37.2]
sobre un máximo de 30 saltos:

  1     1 ms     5 ms   156 ms  ARCHER_XR500V [192.168.1.1]
  2     4 ms     8 ms     4 ms  host-cotesma-161-220-8.smandes.com.ar [201.220.161.8]
  3     4 ms     4 ms     3 ms  10.6.127.45
  4     3 ms     4 ms     3 ms  10.6.127.78
  5     5 ms     6 ms     7 ms  10.32.113.253
  6    22 ms    23 ms    29 ms  8-243-19-6.gblx.net.ar [8.243.19.6]
  7    27 ms    29 ms    29 ms  8-243-19-5.gblx.net.ar [8.243.19.5]
  8    36 ms    28 ms    38 ms  ae1.3502.edge2.Santiago1.level3.net [4.69.216.2]
```

I actually get low latency from my nearest edge location!

So Images are coming from my nearest edge location but thats all, not the whole website. I can actually navigate the website at `du4or9u9pzqwh.cloudfront.net`

so I guess the distribution is working properly, and its actually connecting to my nearest location. for some reason the main domain name oasisdigital.com.ar isn't.

Comment: Can you show us how you have configured the DNS record?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I used [WPAdmin AWS CDN](https://wordpress.org/plugins/aws-cdn-by-wpadmin/) to setup the distribution, I have checked SiteGround DNS Zone editor and I can´t see any record pointing to the CloudFront Distribution but somehow im getting website images from the CDN

Comment: at Domain Name Registrar It´s pointing to ns1.siteground.net and ns2.siteground.net. by the way I think you got the link of where the image is pointing too, which is another page and not the source link of the image as I get https://du4or9u9pzqwh.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/LIVING-PATAGONIA-2.png

Comment: Oops! You are quite correct. The image URL is `https://du4or9u9pzqwh.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/LIVING-PATAGONIA-2.png`. Therefore, try `nslookup du4or9u9pzqwh.cloudfront.net` For me, it resolves to four IP addresses like `13.224.177.5`, which are in Sydney (where I am located).

Comment: FYI, that image is 1.4MB, which will take a while for users to download (and there's three such images). If you load it into a graphics editor you can save it with a lower quality (not perceptible to humans) and make it 25% of the size. The page will load a lot faster.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein just updated the post with the info you requested and something more. Was DNS properly configurated? Thanks for the heads up will optimize images too.

Comment: If you want the whole website to be served via CloudFront, then you will need to edit your DNS configuration for `oasisdigital.com.ar`. Create a `CNAME` record that points to: `du4or9u9pzqwh.cloudfront.net`. Then, you can remove the WordPress plugin.

Comment: CNAME record was the missing piece of the puzzle, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that you are wanting to serve your WordPress website via CloudFront.

After creating and testing the CloudFront definition, you can then **reconfigure your Domain Name to point to CloudFront**.

You would create a `CNAME` record that points to `du4or9u9pzqwh.cloudfront.net`.

Then, all requests sent to your domain will be sent to the CloudFront distribution.